# How do I generate XML resources at runtime on Android?

Tags: android, xml, localization, runtime

I have different strings.xml files in my resources folders (values, values_fr, values_de...), and I would like to load additional translations during runtime. Is it possible to add the new strings to those files even if it has already been compiled? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't. You can't modify hard-coded stuff into APK resources.

But there are some options. For instance you can:

- Let's say read a resource, modify it, and save it into another external folder (SD card or so)
- Create [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) over those file(s)
- Then create [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) which can be later used as ordinary Android resource stored in APK

Comment: Ok, thanks! That seems to be what I need. Is it possible to load through "AssetManager" something else than XML ? For example JSON or formatted string ?

Comment: I don't know about possibility to load JSON - sorry.

Comment: @Hrk: Yes it is. You can load anything you want as a raw stream from an asset: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you barmaley but how do you do step 2? There is no constructor for AssetManager. Thanks in advance, Barry

Comment: Turns out AssetManager does have a public constructor, but bizarrely it is not in the SDK docs. :(