# Remove items programmatically from string-array ressources

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-listview

i have a sting array containing these elements

```
<string-array name="actions">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
    </string-array>
```

i want to access to this string array "actions" and modify programmatically in it i mean like removing and adding items but in java not in xml .is there any solution to do that ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource files  are constants you can't change them in the run time , but there are some alternatives you can do , take look  on it :

[How do I generate XML resources at runtime on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591696/android-how-to-generate-xml-resources-on-runtime)

[Is it possible to change the value of a string added in res/strings.xml on Android at run time/ or by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258650/is-it-possible-to-change-value-of-string-added-in-res-strings-xml-in-android-at)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically modify the resources.

What you can do is to create a separate list of strings and initially copy the strings from the resources into it. You can then modify the list as you wish.