# How to use an AssetManager for loading additional localized resources?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-resources

I found an idea here:
[Using an AssetManager for resource loading at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591696/android-how-to-generate-xml-resources-on-runtime#)

How can I implement it? Kindly could somebody help me with more information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ex: Place your text file in the /Assets ... /Assets/example.txt

```
public class ReadAsset : Activity
{
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    InputStream input = Assets.Open ("my_asset.txt");
}
}
```

Or you can also put the file in the /Resources/raw... /Resources/raw/example

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.example);
```

Or you can load html from asset and load in webview:

```
 webview.loadUrl("file:///asset/aboutcertified.html");
```

Additionally, some Android functions will automatically load asset files:

/Assets/fonts/samplefont.ttf

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Context.Assets, "fonts/samplefont.ttf");
```

For more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Comment: I meant loading language resources not from values, but from any downloaded file with an AssetManager

Comment: Its not possible with AssetManager because, its created for loading file from assets/Resources. you could download and read/write file in private context of application

Comment: See this example: http://jmsliu.com/1954/android-save-downloading-file-locally.html